# linux get process from background and send again

Tags: linux, background-task

Send process to background:

```
gedit &
```

get process from background:

```
fg %!1
```

How I can to send again this process to background ? Is for that any command /key combination ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `CTRL+Z` and type `bg` for background.

...and you should probably ask in the Unix/Linux or the SuperUser forums next time since your question is not about programming.